# With H2 Database can I perform a SQL query on CSV text read from a Java Reader e.g. StringReader?

Tags: java, sql, database, csv, h2

Is there a way to perform SQL queries on CSV text held in memory and read in from a Java Reader e.g. StringReader.

org.h2.tools.Csv.read(Reader reader, String[] colNames) would allow me to retrieve a result set containing all the rows and columns. However, I actually want to perform a query on the CSV text read from the Reader.

The background - I receive a file containing multiple CSV sections for each entity, see [Can H2 Database query a CSV file containing multiple sections of different record groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8067343/316566), and whilst parsing the file I store each of the CSV sections I need in Strings (a String for each one). This shouldn't bog down memory as I only keep the data in memory for a short time and each CSV section is relatively small). I need to perform queries on these CSV sections to build a document in a custom format.

I could write each CSV section to a file (as a set of files) and use CSVREAD, but I don't want to do that as I need my application to be as fast as possible and splitting and writing the sections to disk will thrash the hard drive to death.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a [user defined function](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions) that returns a result set, and use that to generate the required rows. Within your user defined function, you can use the Csv tool from H2 (actually any Csv tool).

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean. So maybe it might be a useful feature to add to the H2 Database: to include a built-in function CSVREAD(String csvcontent) ... like CSVREAD(filename), but instead of passing in the name of the CSV file, you pass in a string containing the actual CSV content. Of course this would only be useful if the CSV data is relatively small.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly, since DBMS can usually only query their own optimized data storage. You have to import the text with the mentioned `org.h2.tools.Csv.read` into a table and perform the queries on that table. The table may be a temporary one, to prevent any writes on the disk, assuming the memory is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean, but so far I haven't been able to find an H2 Database Java API call to directly create a new table (temporary one) directly from the resultset returned by org.h2.tools.Csv.read(...). Otherwise, I have to cycle through each row in the resultset (in Java) and insert each row into a newly created temporary table (quite long winded). However, please let me know if there is indeed such a Java API call (to directly create a table from a resultset).