# Is there a Java library which will enable me to easily extract data from CSV text held in a String

Tags: java, csv

I'm looking for a Java library which will enable me to easily extract data from a specific column (or multiple columns) of CSV text held in memory e.g. in a String.

For example, extract each 'town' value in the records below into an `ArrayList<String>` object or `String[]`. Or even further, extract all 'town' and 'country' values from every record.

... I preferably need a solution that doesn't rely on the columns being in fixed positions.

```
ADDRESS|HOUSE_NO|STREET|TOWN|CITY|COUNTY|COUNTRY
DATA|51|Hill Road|Reading|Berkshire|United Kingdom
DATA|78|Crescent Road|Wallingford|Oxfordshire|United Kingdom
DATA|5|Bonny Crescent|Swindon|Whiltshire|United Kingdom
```

... note that the entire CSV section in the above example is contained in memory in a single String.

I have already been looking at the option of using an in-memory database engine like H2, but it can't seem to handle running SQL queries against CSV text that's held in memory e.g. in a String. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if I'll get a solution to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8115157/316566, that's why I'm looking at non-database solutions (as in my above question)

Answer (score 2):

I use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) in all my projects.  Its a pretty good library, and is available in Maven central so if you are using maven its really easy to add to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use String.split

```
String[] tokens = myString.split("\\|");
```

But I'd like to point out that if you have a database, you shouldn't be storing it as a CSV. You should make a table and have columns for that. So I would strongly consider doing this before you put it in the database, and putting it in the proper columns at that time.

If the ENTIRE file is a single string, I'd do this:

```
final String delim = "\\|";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(csvFile);
String headersRaw = sc.nextLine();
String[] headers = headersRaw.split(delim);
// process headers if necessary
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] tokens = sc.nextLine().split(delim);
    // process tokens here
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous if reading from a file in which a single row may have embedded new lines.

Comment: Yes, `String.split` is fine, but I don't want to rely on the columns always being in the same order. As such, I would have to read in the header and store the position (index) of each column, etc. That would be fine for one or two CSV tables, but there are loads of different ones I need to process. I actually have a single file containing loads of different CSV sections to process in my program, so that's why I read each CSV section into a String for further processing. I am not using a database so far, but am considering http://stackoverflow.com/q/8067343/316566